# Tiles aren't got successfully from geoserver

Tags: javascript, openlayers, geojson, geoserver

I want to pick up from the GeoServer vector tile on the GeoServer there is a gridset and a layer caching tiles in geojson. I used a standart Geoserver Vector tiles tutorial. As a result, openlayers refers, in the browser debuger a bunch of requests to the tiles but they are all 400, and respons is cryptic for me:

```
Coverage [minx,miny,maxx,maxy] is [19, 21, 19, 21, 4], index [x,y,z] is [8, 5, 4]
```

(in accord with a particular request to tile)

this is VectorTile source code:

```
 //style:simpleStyle,
   source: new ol.source.Vector Tile({
   tilePixelRatio: 1, // oversampling when > 1
   tileGrid: ol.tilegrid.createXYZ({maxZoom: 19}),
   format: new ol.format.GeoJSON(),
       url: 'localhost:8080/geoserver/gwc/service/tms/1.0.0/' + layer
   +projection_epsg_no+'@geojson/{z}/{x}/{y}.geojson'
 })
});
```

What the problem? why tiles isn't got?

**UPD:** geojson doesn't display correct in geoserver viewer too. If I use png/jpeg a layer displays correctly

**UPD#2** in some zoom level request's response 'Zoom level was 619, but value has to be in [0,22]' in some zoome level (4 and less) 'Coverage [minx,miny,maxx,maxy] is [307, 345, 310, 349, 9], index [x,y,z] is [3, 4, 9]'

```
//map code
var map = new ol.Map({
        target: 'map',
        layers: [
          new ol.layer.Tile({
            source: new ol.source.OSM()
          }),
          vectorPoints // there is vector tile layer
          //geoserverLayer
        ],
        controls: [slaceline, overview, zoom, mouseXY],

        view: new ol.View({
          center: ol.proj.fromLonLat([ 37.37, 55.45]),
          zoom: 4
        })
      });
```

boundary box: 35.886707453762355, 53.32025750684015, 38.60726427487116, 54.850739937656314

Comment: Presumably you are expecting data in this area https://i.stack.imgur.com/tRKrO.png ?  tms usually uses {-y} in the source url as the origin is bottom left, but I think you have a non-standard tile grid which has 4 tiles at level 0 instead of 1 tile so you will need a custom tile url function.

Comment: no, 0 level has 1 tile. And  geojson doesn't display correct in geoserver viewer too. If I use png/jpeg a layer displays correctly

Comment: @Mike this issue could links with styles?

Comment: I don't think it is a style problem, the server setup for geojson tiles seems to be wrong.  The message makes sense if the server thinks it has no data where you are trying to view it e.g. https://maps4.nyc.gov/tms/1.0.0/carto/basemap/8/75/155.jpg but I presume you should have data where [x,y,z] is [8, 5, 4]?

Comment: what is your source datastore? is it correctly projected? what is your epsg_no?

Comment: The error is saying it expects x to be between 19&21 and you asked for 8 so there is no tile to give you. most likely a projection issue

Comment: @IanTurton yes, It looks good (Image tiles works fine). EPGS n is 3857(Pseudo-mercator).

Comment: Is your map in 3857?

Comment: @IanTurton yes a source of layer in 3857, this epgs value set in layer configs and grid set config. Everywhere 3857. And png/jpeg tiles looks good on osm (osm  3857 too)

Comment: can you add the map creation code, the actual tile request url and your bounding box

Comment: Your bounding box is in lat/lon degrees so it won't match your data, which indicates that either OL or GS are not in the right projection. Thus, no data will display as it will be either too small or too big for your map depending on which end your mistake is at

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/196647/discussion-between-tyomik-mnemonic-and-ian-turton).

Comment: I had a mistake
yes it is lat/lon, cause I give a Latitude/longitude of the bounding box
3,994,890; 7,042,458; 4,297,741; 7,332,951.5 is real values. and it is looks good. I think it is not proj problem...